# How to properly set the data in swagger-js client for a PUT request which requires BOTH formData and path parameters?

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a method that requires both **formData** and **path** parameters. How can I set the data in the request?

I am using swagger-js v2.

Let's say the example below requires 3 parameters:

1. `ResetPassword` is a **path** parameter
2. `password` is a **formData** parameter
3. `repeat_password` is a **formData** parameter

```js
swagger_client.apis.users.resetPassword(<HELP!!>, 
function(response) {
    // success
}, function(err) {
    // failure
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant for you but I stucked at the same problem and found a solution.

Define your parameter object like this:

```js
var paramObj = {
                              ResetPassword: "resetpw",
                              parameterContentType: "multipart/form-data",
                              password: formData1,
                              repeat_password: formData2

                           };
```

then call with

```
swagger_client.apis.users.resetPassword(paramObj,...
```